# Need suggestions for a Streaming Application

Tags: jakarta-ee, web

I am planning to develop a  Trading Application (Continuous Streaming of data of some selected stocks  )

At present , I could able to make a request to the exchange and get the Data of a stock .

I want to display the Stock Data with streaming in my web application .

Could anybody please tell me what would be the technology to be choose for this purpose ??

(I am into Java J2EE platform .)

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a REST resource (with for example JAX-RS) which will provide data changes since given time and consume this resource from javascript (using for example jQuery AJAX https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). I'm not sure if you have any fornt-end to display stock data, if not you can give a try to HighStock (http://www.highcharts.com/products/highstock). I've been successfully using it some time ago. 
The other way for retrieving data from server are websockets, but be careful with this, because not all mobile browsers support it. Websockets hold connection between client and server so you could simply send stock data changes to client via websocket and implement a handler on client side which will react to 'new data' events.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , i have a question , even though i use REST how it can make continuous requests to the URL ??

Comment: You can create a timer in front-end which will execute some logic after specified period of time.